# Meteor prodution database connection

Tags: meteor

We are running two apps on same server.1st app mongo database connect to 27107 and works fine and the 2nd app mongo database connecting but connection close with in few seconds used same port 2017.mateor app not running.

Comment: Are you passing different `--port` arguments to the two apps? If not they will both try to run on 3000. Was the database started independently from meteor (i.e. you are not using the default meteor development database)?

Comment: Accessing same database at time for two apps.Meteor running on the two different ports i.e 3000 and 4000.@ David Weldon